# Deleting derived class through base class pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, abstract-data-type

I have an interface that represent ADT 'Bag'. To implement that abstract data type I used Array based and Linked based implementation.

Here the definition of class

**edit As you indicated, i've added virtual destructor to my Base class**

```
template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface{

public:
    ... some methods

   ~BagInterface();
};


#endif /* BagInterface_hpp */
```

And my 2 derived class implement these methods on their way.

My link based implementation is using virtual destructor because unlike array based implementation it's dynamically allocating memory and eventually it has to delete instance by using 'delete' keyword due to avoid from memory leaks.

destructor of linked bag

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType>::~LinkedBag(){
    clear(); // Clears bag's content.
}
```

destructor of arraybag

```
template<class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>::~ArrayBag(){
    clear();
}
```

I've created a function that takes a pointer as a input to represent bag in order to test my implementations.

```
void bagTester(BagInterface<int>* bagPtr){
   // do some test }
```

I'd like to delete my derived class through base class pointers in the following.

```
  int main() {
     BagInterface<int>* bagPtr = nullptr; // base class pointer
    
     char userChoice;
     cin>> userChoice;
    
     if(userChoice == 'A'){
     bagPtr = new ArrayBag<int>(); // Array based implementation 
    }else if(userChoice == 'L'){
     bagPtr = new LinkedBag<int>(); // Link based implementation
    }

    bagTester(bagPtr); // test my bag
    
    delete bagPtr; // and now i'm finished with test let's delete the object
    bagPtr = nullptr; // to avoid dangling pointers
}
```

In that point my error is occurring, compiler gives a warning ->

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
In file included from ./LinkedBag.hpp:5:
./BagInterface.hpp:36:31: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    virtual ~BagInterface() = default;
                              ^
In file included from main.cpp:4:
./ArrayBag.hpp:28:5: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
    ~ArrayBag();
    ^
main.cpp:48:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'ArrayBag<int>' requested here
        bagPtr = new ArrayBag<int>();
                     ^
./BagInterface.hpp:36:13: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual ~BagInterface() = default;
            ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:
./LinkedBag.hpp:25:1: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
~LinkedBag();
^
main.cpp:52:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'LinkedBag<int>' requested here
        bagPtr = new LinkedBag<int>();
                     ^
./BagInterface.hpp:36:13: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual ~BagInterface() = default;
            ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

So, how can I avoid from the warning?

Comment: "tried to add virtual destructor to BagInterface, but it didn't work" Let's make this our starting point. You add a virtual destructor to BagInterface because not having a virtual destructor there is wrong. So everything that was before you added the virtual destructor is wrong. Now that you have a virtual destructor, describe your problem.

Comment: you realize that right now you leak memory because link based implementations' destructor is not called through your `delete bagPtr`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But without adding virtual destructor to BagInterface at least i can compile with warning, but when i add virtual destructor to BagInterface i can't even compile, it gives bunch of errors...

Comment: Let's try again. Not having a virtual destructor is wrong. Having a virtual destructor is right. However having a virtual destructor alone doesn't guarantee correctness. You might have other things that are wrong with your code. You however don't share your errors, so we cannot tell what these wrong things are. If you want your question answered, you ought to actually post your actual errors as printed by the compiler. "It didn't work" is no useful information. We can guess it didn't work. You probably wouldn't be here otherwise.

Comment: To be clear: if a program deletes an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base and the base does not have a virtual destructor, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: Adding a virtual destructor to `BagInterface` is a correct solution. Could you edit your question to show that code and ask about the errors it generates? (I would even start with that and move most of the context after the question. Get people interested right away instead of getting them to ask "is this question going somewhere?")

Comment: I'm going to edit my question according to your suggestions give me a min...

Comment: One thing you'll find in programing is sometimes fixing a mistake reveals more mistakes. Do not assume code that compiles is closer to correct than code that does not compile. It is very easy to write code that compiles and is logically incorrect. In addition, sometimes you can add a much needed semicolon or close brace and see the error list grow from one  error to hundreds because the compiler can now interpret more of the code and render commentary on its correctness. Do what is right and then hash out whatever "new" mistakes are revealed.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. first of all i'm so new at this platform, and you are right i had to be more clear 'it didn't work' is a not a good explanation. Thanks for all of your advice i'll try improve myself when i explain my question. Now i've edited my question according to your suggestions...

Comment: Your compiler is so old it defaults to C++2003 standard. You may want to add `-std=c++11` flag to all your compilation commands. Does this get rid of the errors? Better yet, upgrade to a modern release.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. now it has fixed... Omg first of all big thanks to everyone, second of all i'm such a novice, i can feel it probably i got on your nerves. But thanks i've learned lot from this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, when you run this code :

```
delete bagPtr;
```

the destructor from the link based implementation isn't called.

```
template<class ItemType>
class BagInterface{

public:
.....
virtual ~BagInterface() = default;
};
```

You need this destructor if you are going to delete a class derived from BagInterface through a pointer to BagInterface (or if a `sharedpointer<BagInterface>` pointing to a derived class from BagInterface  goes out of scope).

> My link based implementation is using virtual destructor because
> unlike array based implementation it's dynamically allocating memory
> and eventually it has to delete instance by using 'delete' keyword due
> to avoid from memory leaks.

This is why you need a virtual destructor in your base class : if you don't have one, when you delete a derived class through a pointer of the base class, you get undefined behaviour.

> Deleting an object through pointer to base invokes undefined behavior
> unless the destructor in the base class is virtual.
> [source here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

Comment: It’s worse than a memory leak. The behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you so much...

Comment: @user Really appreciated...